# Error in code for bulk whatsapp sender using Excel VBA. The code sends message to first person in the list and then shows run time error 462

Tags: excel, vba, whatsapp

its showing Run time error 462, the remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable.

Here is the code -

```
Sub EP03_SendWhatsAppMessagesWithMultiImages()
   'API -   "whatsapp://send?phone=phone_number&text=your_message"
   Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
   Dim strUrl As String
   Dim index As Integer
   
   Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer
          ieApp.Visible = True
          
    For index = 2 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
      strUrl = "whatsapp://send?phone=" & Range("A" & index).Value & "&text=" & Range("B" & index).Value
      
      ieApp.Navigate strUrl
      If (Range("C" & index).Value <> "") Then
          Sheet1.Pictures.Insert (Range("C" & index).Value)
          Sheet1.Shapes(1).Copy
          Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 4)
          Application.SendKeys "^v"
         Sheet1.Shapes(1).Delete
   End If
      Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
      Application.SendKeys "~"
     Next index
      
      ieApp.Quit
      
End Sub
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a solution to this error, can it be fixed by tweaking the code?

Comment: Does it work it you single step through it slowly with F8 ? try adding another wait after `Application.SendKeys "~"`

Comment: @CDP1802  Tried, didn't work. debug shows issue with 
`ieApp.Navigate  strUrl` line

Comment: Is IE still open? Perhaps you can make an error handler for this error to recreate a new instance of IE to `ieApp` and resume. Or store the pointer of the object and make the error handler restore the object. Or use something more stable like Selenium (IE is old..)

Comment: @RaymondWu I am really noob at this, can you please provide the code and where I should add it?

Comment: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/ Please read this on how to do error handling for your code. The basic code in your error handler will be something like - `Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer: Resume`. You will have to consider other possiblity of where the code can fail and you might need to do `.Navigate` in addition to just recreating a new instance.

Comment: If you can use Selenium, i will suggest you try that instead. @Learner

Comment: @RaymondWu thank you so much brother. it worked.